# Typescript:What does ? syntax in the code below

Tags: typescript

```js
 class DataQuery {
    size?: number;
    searchAfter?: FieldId;
    sort?: DataQuerySort[];
    groupings?: FieldId[];
    fields?: FieldId[];
    filters?: DataQueryFilter[];
}
```

I am new to typescript

I am unable to understand what does this class doing( because of the ? syntax) .Can any one explain this ?

Comment: Not sure what is unclear, have you read the handbook ? http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Optional fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties marked with '?' are optional, their value can be either the defined type or undefined. See the [Optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) section